# Insertar texto en una posición con React AceEditor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

he consultado la librería [AceEditor de React](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace/blob/master/docs/Ace.md), y veo que no tiene la opción `editor.session.insert({row:number,column:number}, text)` como lo hace nativamente JavaScript usando la libreria. Alguien sabe si hay manera de hacerlo en React?. Vi en los props que existe `setOptions` y muestra las lista disponibles para hacerla las opciones y no sale el de insertar posicion.

Intenté con el `cursorStart` pero siempre me deja en la ultima posicion del texto, cuando le pongo un `value`.

Sobre la respuesta que hizo @Alter Lagos. Yo lo tengo tomando del `ref` y no muestra esa opción de `editor.insert`. Te muestro la imagen de la consola y el código como lo tengo.

Claramente ese `onChange` se le hace un `useState`, para colocarlo en el `value`. solo lo hice de ejemplo, es para que vean como uso el `ref`. Ese `ref` lo huso en el componente padre para obtener la ubicación del cursor para poder colocar un `string` en la posición correcta usando `drag and drop`.

Imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```js
import React, { memo, useRef } from 'react';
import AceEditor from 'react-ace';
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-kuroir';
import 'ace-builds/webpack-resolver';

const SQLContainerInput = memo({
  const sqlInputRef = useRef(null);
  
  const changeEditor = () => {
    console.log(sqlInputRef?.current);
  }
  
  return(
    <AceEditor
      mode="mysql"
      theme="kuroir"
      height={300}
      width="100%"
      name="editorSqlId"
      fontSize={12}
      cursorStart={4}
      editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
      highlightActiveLine={false}
      onLoad={(e) => console.log(e, 'eddd')}
      onChange={changeEditor}
      ref={sqlInputRef}
      setOptions={{
        showLineNumbers: true,
        tabSize: 2,
      }}
    />
  );
});

export default SQLContainerInput;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo [en el código de componente](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace/blob/001bc1cd787c990422437e70abb5856f4d2704b4/src/ace.tsx) alguna parte donde se llame a `insert`, así que lo más probable es que no esté implementado. Ahora, tomando como referencia [parte de lo que describen en este issue](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace/issues/348), pareciese que puedes definir una referencia en tu componente como:

```
<AceEditor ref="tuEditor" />
```

y luego, donde corresponda, llamar a:

```
this.refs.tuEditor.editor.insert({row:number,column:number}, text)
```

nunca he usado esta librería, pero me da a pensar que pueda funcionar, ya que `editor` [está definido como público](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace/blob/001bc1cd787c990422437e70abb5856f4d2704b4/src/ace.tsx#L162).